# Refresh on submit behaving weirdly

Tags: php, mysql, forms, submit

I would expect that the below code would cause the page to refresh when I pressed any of the CALLED or EMAILED buttons but it does not appear to be doing so. I click the button and the page does not refresh but when I press F5 the change shows up to the relevant field.

Can anyone offer some thoughts on why it's not refreshing? I need to force the whole page to refresh whenever the submit button is clicked. I'm open to JS solutions as well but the quirky behavior is making it hard to figure out what's going on. Thanks for the help!

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Call Log System</title>

<style type="text/css">

@-webkit-keyframes invalid {
  from { background-color: red; }
  to { background-color: inherit; }
}
@-moz-keyframes invalid {
  from { background-color: red; }
  to { background-color: inherit; }
}
@-o-keyframes invalid {
  from { background-color: red; }
  to { background-color: inherit; }
}
@keyframes invalid {
  from { background-color: red; }
  to { background-color: inherit; }
}
.invalid {
  -webkit-animation: invalid 3s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    invalid 3s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      invalid 3s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         invalid 3s infinite; /* IE 10+ */
}
</style>




<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkDelete(){
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');
}
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkArchive(){
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to archive this record?');
}
</script>


</head>

<body>


<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = '********';
$db_pwd = '******';
$database = '********';
$table = 'Project_Submissions';


if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");
if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

//Display all fields
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE Archived is null or Archived='' ORDER BY ID DESC");

if (!$result) 
{
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

echo "<a href=\"archives.php\">Go to Archives</a>";
//Main Table 
echo "<table border='1px' width='100%'>
<tr>
<th style='font-size:18px;width:20px;'>ID</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Customer Name</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Phone #</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Address</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Time Zone</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>E-mail</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Alt Phone</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Vehicle</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Project Start</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Project Description</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>RDM</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Phone Call #1</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Phone Call #2</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Phone Call #3</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Email Sent</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Notes</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Received Date</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Functions</th>
</tr>";


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $mydate = $row['Received_Date'];
    $receiveddate = strtotime($mydate);
    $onemonthago = strtotime('-1 month');
    $twomonthago = strtotime('-2 month');
    $threemonthago = strtotime('-3 month');

    if($receiveddate > $onemonthago)//Less than 30 days old
    {
        echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#74ED45\">";//Green
    }

    else if(($receiveddate > $twomonthago) && ($receiveddate < $onemonthago))//30-60 days old
    {
        echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#EDED45\">";//Yellow
    }
    else if(($receiveddate > $threemonthago) && ($receiveddate < $twomonthago))//60-90 days old
    {
        echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#D65151\">";//Red
    }
    else if($receiveddate < $threemonthago)//More than 90 days old
    {
        //echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#2C32DB\">";//Blue
        echo "<tr class=\"invalid\">";//Flashing Red
    }

    else 
    {
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    echo "
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['ID']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'>{$row['First_Name']} {$row['Last_Name']}</td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><a href=\"tel:{$row['Phone']}\">{$row['Phone']}</a></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Street']} {$row['City']} {$row['State_Country']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><div style=\"width:150px\">{$row['Time_Zone']}</div></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><a href=\"mailto:{$row['Email']}?Subject=************\" target=\"_top\">{$row['Email']}</a></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Alt_Phone']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Year']} {$row['Make']} {$row['Model']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Project_Start']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;width:300px;'><div style=\"overflow-x:auto; max-height:100px\">{$row['Project_Description']}</div></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Restoration_Decision_Matrix']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>";

    //------------------------------------
    if(empty($row['CallAttemptOne']))
    {
    echo" 
        <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='{$row['ID']}' />
        <input type='submit' name='formCalledOne' id='formCalledOne' value='Called' />
        </form>
        {$row['CallAttemptOne']}";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "{$row['CallAttemptOne']}";
    }


    echo "</center></td><td style='font-size:12px;'><center>";

    //------------------------------------
    if(empty($row['CallAttemptTwo']))
    {
    echo" 
        <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='{$row['ID']}' />
        <input type='submit' name='formCalledTwo' id='formCalledTwo' value='Called' />
        </form>
        {$row['CallAttemptTwo']}";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "{$row['CallAttemptTwo']}";
    }


    echo "</center></td><td style='font-size:12px;'><center>";

    //------------------------------------
    if(empty($row['CallAttemptThree']))
    {
    echo" 
        <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='{$row['ID']}' />
        <input type='submit' name='formCalledThree' id='formCalledThree' value='Called' />
        </form>
        {$row['CallAttemptThree']}";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "{$row['CallAttemptThree']}";
    }


    echo "</center></td><td style='font-size:12px;'><center>";

    //------------------------------------
    if(empty($row['EmailAttempt']))
    {
    echo" 
        <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='{$row['ID']}' />
        <input type='submit' name='formEmailAttempt' id='formEmailAttempt' value='Emailed' />
        </form>
        {$row['EmailAttempt']}";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "{$row['EmailAttempt']}";
    }


    echo "</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;width:300px;'><center>Text Area</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Received_Date']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>

        <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post' onclick=\"return checkDelete()\">
        <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='{$row['ID']}' />
        <input type='submit' name='formDelete' id='formDelete' value='Delete' />
        </form>

        <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post' onclick=\"return checkArchive()\">
        <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='{$row['ID']}' />
        <input type='submit' name='formArchive' id='formArchive' value='Archive' />
        </form>


    </center></td>
    </tr>";



    //Check to see if delete button is pressed
    if(isset($_POST['formDelete']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
        {
            $deleteID = $_POST['ID'];
            $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Project_Submissions WHERE ID ='".$deleteID."'");
        }
    }   

    //Check to see if archive button is pressed
    if(isset($_POST['formArchive']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
        {
            $archiveID = $_POST['ID'];
            $result = mysql_query("UPDATE Project_Submissions SET Archived ='1' WHERE ID ='".$archiveID."'");
        }
    }   

    if(isset($_POST['formCalledOne']))//Check to see if Call Attempt One button is pressed
    {
        //if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
        //{
            $callattemptoneID = $_POST['ID'];
            $callattemptonequery = mysql_query("UPDATE Project_Submissions SET CallAttemptOne=CURDATE() WHERE ID ='".$callattemptoneID."' AND (CallAttemptOne IS NULL OR LENGTH(CallAttemptOne)=0)");
        //}
    }   

    if(isset($_POST['formCalledTwo']))//Check to see if Call Attempt Two button is pressed
    {
        //if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
        //{
            $callattempttwoID = $_POST['ID'];
            $callattempttwoquery = mysql_query("UPDATE Project_Submissions SET CallAttemptTwo=CURDATE() WHERE ID ='".$callattempttwoID."' AND (CallAttemptTwo IS NULL OR LENGTH(CallAttemptTwo)=0)");
        //}
    }   

    if(isset($_POST['formCalledThree']))//Check to see if Call Attempt Three button is pressed
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
        {
            $callattemptthreeID = $_POST['ID'];
            $callattemptthreequery = mysql_query("UPDATE Project_Submissions SET CallAttemptThree=CURDATE() WHERE ID ='".$callattemptthreeID."' AND (CallAttemptThree IS NULL OR LENGTH(CallAttemptThree)=0)");
        }
    }   

    if(isset($_POST['formEmailAttempt']))//Check to see if Email Attempt button is pressed
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
        {
            $emailattemptID = $_POST['ID'];
            $emailattemptquery = mysql_query("UPDATE Project_Submissions SET EmailAttempt=CURDATE() WHERE ID ='".$emailattemptID."' AND (EmailAttempt IS NULL OR LENGTH(EmailAttempt)=0)");

        }
    }   
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: This is what the screen looks like]

Comment: Just FYI, LENGTH(EmailAttempt)=0 will cause a full table scan, instead use EmailAttempt=''

Comment: Do you have any Javascript with an `onsubmit` handler that overrides the normal behavior?

Comment: Unless you have Javascript, a form submit should always refresh.

Comment: Nope nothing. I'm going to update the code to make it the complete codeset and see if you guys can see why it's doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, I think this should help.

```
<?php

$value = "string";


if (isset($_POST['ID']))
{
    echo $emailattemptID = $_POST['ID'];
}



echo" 
<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='$value' />
<input type='submit' name='formEmailAttempt' id='formEmailAttempt' value='Emailed' />
</form>
";

?>
```

Comment: hmm?? I'm not sure that makes any sense, can you elaborate?

Comment: you just have to change the variables with yours

Comment: This is a form you can use, and the isset is there to check if you got what you want in the variable.

Comment: But it's not doing anything that my code is doing that I can see.